# Adding "not" to each item in a sequence in Clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, functional-programming, lisp, anonymous-function

I am trying to add `(not(X))` to all my items `X` in a sequence.

For example:

Convert `(a b)` to
`( (not(a)) (not(b)) )`

When I use `(map (fn [x] (not(x))) mylist)`, it tries to evaluate the nots and return booleans.

When I use `(map (fn [x] '(not(x))) mylist)`, it just returns a list of `(not(x))` without actually putting in my list's variables.

`(a b) --> ( (not(a)) (not(b)) )` ? Thanks!

Comment: And just for some context, what do you intend to do with the results?

Comment: `(not(x))` should be throwing an error, unless `x` was a function of no arguments.

Comment: I want to use it as a constant, essentially. I don't need to evaluate "not". I essentially just want to make a function that "nots" all the items in it.

    (defn not-all-items [mylist]
       (turn each item to (not(item)) ))

Comment: I understand that, I am just surprised that you didn't get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user=> (map (fn [x] (list 'not (list x))) '(a b))
((not (a)) (not (b)))
```

The `'` single quote operator is convenient for making lists because it prevents evaluation, but it isn't usable in your case because you have content inside the resulting list that you want to be evaluated.

Another option would have been ` AKA quasiquote, which allows selective unquoting, but also namespaces symbols (once again, not useful in your case, where you want the symbol used literally).

Answer (score 2):

You can make it more readable and get rid of numerous `list` calls
by using syntax-quote reader macro:

```
user> (map (fn [x] `(~'not (~x))) '(a b))
((not (a)) (not (b)))
```

(see clojure reader documentation's section on [syntax quoting](
http://clojure.org/reader))
unquote-quote `not` (`~'not`) is used here to insert literal `not` symbol instead of namespace-prefixed `clojure.core/not`